# In which way I can set multiple stores in my sub domain in Magento version 2.1.7?

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

- In which way i can set multiple store in my sub-domain **Magento version 2.1.7**?
- In Which way I can show multi store option on front page?

Comment: Please see link https://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-multistore-website-shopfront/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link from Magento devdocs.

[Multiple websites or stores](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html)